# BMI Index in Python

Tags: python

I need help with doing the code for my homework, I have a feeling I could be missing something, your help/feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Sincerely 
Meredith

```
def calc_BMI():
   weight=requestNumber("Enter weight (kg)")
   height=requestNumber("Enter Height (meters)")
   bmi=(weight/(height*height))
   print 'Your BMI in %2f' % bmi
   if bmi=<15
      print('Your weight status is Very Severely Underweight')    
   elif bmi>=15.0 and bmi<=16.0
    print ('Your weight status is Severely Underweight')
   elif bmi>=16.0 and bmi<=18.5
    print ('Your weight status is Underweight')
   elif bmi>= 18.5 and bmi <=25       
    print('Your weight staus is Normal')
   elif bmi >=25 and bmi <=30
    print ('Your weight status is Overweight')
   elif bmi>=30 and bmi <=35
    print ('Your weight status is Moderately Obese')
   elif bmi >=35 and bmi<=40
    print ('Your weight status is Severely Obese')
   elif bmi <=40 
    print ('Your weight status is Very Severely Obese')
```

Comment: The last `elif` should have `bmi >= 40`. But what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: Also, you need to add a colon (:) after your `if`s and `elif`s, i.e.: `if bmi <= 15:`. Another thing, your first `if` has the equal before the less-than symbol, you should change it to `if bmi<=15`...

Comment: You may also want to consider simplifying `bmi>=16.0 and bmi<=18.5` to `16.0 >= bmi <= 18.5` and other similar cases.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issue:

Will list them out here:

1. `requestNumber` is not a method in python. Either import a library which has this method. Or use the default `input` method.

`weight = requestNumber("Enter weight (kg)")`

`instead`

`weight = input("Enter weight (kg)")`

2. at the end of if coundition you should have a ':'

eg: `if bmi <= 15:`

Also `if bmi=<15` is wrong. it should be `if bmi <= 15:`

3. remove the enter code here part from your questions.

   `elif bmi >=35 and bmi<=40 enter code here`
4. Bug in your code in the last but 1 line. It should be >=

   `elif bmi <=40`

   `print ('Your weight status is Very Severely Obese')`

Working code:

```
def calc_BMI():
    weight = input("Enter weight (kg)")
    height = input("Enter Height (meters)")
    bmi = (int(weight)/(float(height)**2))
    print('Your BMI in %2f' % bmi)
    if bmi <= 15:
        print('Your weight status is Very Severely Underweight')    
    elif bmi >= 15.0 and bmi <= 16.0:
        print ('Your weight status is Severely Underweight')
    elif bmi >= 16.0 and bmi<= 18.5:
        print ('Your weight status is Underweight')
    elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi <= 25:      
        print('Your weight staus is Normal')
    elif bmi >= 25 and bmi <= 30:
        print('Your weight status is Overweight')
    elif bmi >= 30 and bmi <= 35:
        print('Your weight status is Moderately Obese')
    elif bmi >= 35 and bmi <= 40:
        print('Your weight status is Severely Obese')
    elif bmi >= 40:
        print('Your weight status is Very Severely Obese')
```

Output:

```
calc_BMI()

Enter weight (kg)78
Enter Height (meters)1.8
Your BMI in 24.074074
Your weight staus is Normal
```

Helpful notes:

1. Try to follow coding convention like pep-8 maybe [[Link]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
2. Indent your code properly. See how I have added space before and after '>='. This is also a part of pep-89 convention.

   eg: if weight >= 40:

Comment: I would suggest replacing `float(height) * float(height)` with `float(height)**2`.

Comment: Thank you! I can see the changes made and understand them.

Answer (score 0):

There were several errors in your code,I have commented the problems:

```
def calc_BMI():
   weight=int(input("Enter weight (kg)"))#make sure value taken is int
   height=float(input("Enter Height (meters)"))#make sure value taken is float
   bmi=(weight/(height**2))#use the power operator for squaring instead
   print ('Your BMI in %2f' % bmi)
   if bmi <= 15 :#colon eexpected
         print('Your weight status is Very Severely Underweight')
   elif bmi>=15.0 and bmi<=16.0:#colon eexpected
        print ('Your weight status is Severely Underweight')
   elif bmi>=16.0 and bmi<=18.5:#colon eexpected
        print ('Your weight status is Underweight')
   elif bmi>= 18.5 and bmi <=25 :#colon eexpected
        print('Your weight staus is Normal')
   elif bmi >=25 and bmi <=30:#colon eexpected
        print ('Your weight status is Overweight')
   elif bmi>=30 and bmi <=35:#colon eexpected
        print ('Your weight status is Moderately Obese')
   elif bmi >=35 and bmi<=40:#colon eexpected
        print ('Your weight status is Severely Obese')
   else:#no need for a elif,rather use else for the rest
       print('Your weight status is Very Severely Obese')
calc_BMI()# call the function to run
```